# Clear all "tech you like" tags when you've typed too many

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I accidentally copied and pasted a bunch of sentences I had from an email into the tech I like tag filter for jobs.  I see you can X out of each tag you don't want but is it worth having a "Clear All" option in the job filters:

[image]

Comment: _"convoluted", "confusing", "hell", "decipher", "mystified", "surprise"_... quite a mail you were sending.

Comment: Note that this request might also be applicable to questions, they have the same issue (you can copy paste sentences in the tag field there too). You can just keep backspace pressed there, unless you just copy-pasted your entire thesis.

Comment: @yivi - I know funny right?  It was an email from an employee telling me about a fired employee's way of working documentation...strange people we are!

Comment: The only good news is that the list isn't sorted; the new tags were added at the end.  I'm not sure what happens to duplicated tags.  That makes it easier (but not easy) to clean up.

Comment: Is there also a UI bug in this screenshot? A bunch of the main page content is visible through the footer of the dialog.

Comment: @Cory yes it is a bug

Comment: @JonH, why strange? Having "full electronic set" is cool! :)

Comment: I... kind of want to see the original email, now. It seems like an interesting read. Or a good story for [TDWTF](http://thedailywtf.com)

Comment: Note sure what you mean, could you make it a bit more clear with a nice red cirkel?

Answer (score 30):

This is still a text field, set cursor at the end, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd> to select all text and then <kbd>DELETE</kbd> to clear it (or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to slowly unselect tags from beginning, kind of *editing*).

Comment: Highlighting with the mouse doesn't seem to work though - and that (I suspect) would be how most people try to clear them...

Comment: What about tablet or phone? But I guess they have some "long-press" + "select-all" feature.